# How do I use Xen hypervisor?

Tags: xen

I am interested in trying out Xen;

- What packages do I need to install?
- How do I set up a DomU instance?

Comment: You don't mention what version of Ubuntu you are running, but have you checked out this Wiki page? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

Comment: I assumed Natty for my answer (Xen with Natty seems broken at the network detection phase). Use the link above for Lucid.

Comment: this question has some directions on what you need to install http://askubuntu.com/q/83846/17034

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Paravirtualized guest** and **Ubuntu 11.04**

When installing a Xen virtual machine, you need to determine what kind of block devices you want to work with. There are three possibilities: installing directly on a dedicated partition (maximum performance) or by using an important disk image file or create your own disk image file with dd (resizable; You can use snapshots for making backups)

All commands assume `root` (ie. `sudo su`). I also assume using LVM but have also included an untested method where you use `dd` to use your own image. So skip 1 if you want to use a file (and not LVM) and skip 2 if you do use LVM.

1. Create a new LVM volume for your virtual machine. Change the name (after `-n`) to suit your needs:

   ```
   lvcreate -L10G -n example.ubuntu.natty VolumeGroup
   ```

   `lvcreate` is part of [lvm2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lvm2) [image: Install lvm2] but it is already installed when you are using lvms.
2. You can also use a file (`dd`). I have not found a suitable method for this with Ubuntu but [this](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/tip/Virtual-machine-installation-Managing-Xen-block-devices) should come close. If you go with this I have experience with it but all the next steps should be the same. Copied from the link the method to create one using `dd` (the link also includes other methods of getting a file):

   Create a 4Gb empty file with at `/var/lib/xen/images/disk1` (change either size and location to fit your needs):

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/xen/images/disk1 bs=1M count=4096
   ```

   Apart from creating empty image files using the dd utility, you can also use ISO files as an alternative for your physical optical drives. The usage is the same as the usage of a disk image file created with dd. Don't have an ISO file yet? Then we have good news for you; it's easy to create one. If the cd-rom of which you want to create an ISO file is in your optical drive, use the following to copy it to a file with the name cdrom.iso:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/isos/cdrom.iso
   ```

   After creating either a disk image file or an ISO file, you need to include the disk image file in your virtual machine configuration using the file option in the disk definition:

   ```
   disk=[ 'file:/var/lib/xen/images/disk1,hda,w', 'file:/isos/cdrom.iso,hdc,r', ]
   ```
3. Get the `kernel`, `initrd`, and `xen config`. `wget` versions for `nl` and `installer-amd64` (so change the country code `nl` and also use `installer-amd64` in the URL to fit your needs):

   ```
   wget http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/xen/xm-debian.cfg
   wget http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/xen/initrd.gz
   wget http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/xen/vmlinuz
   ```
4. Edit the config file

   Edit the config file to taste, paying attention to the memory, name, vcpus, vif, and disk options. Also, find the line that says `bootloader=pygrub` and change it to the absolute path `bootloader=/usr/sbin/pygrub`.
5. Start the install (again pay attention to the command: change server country code and architecture to your needs):

   ```
   xm create -f xm-debian.cfg -c install=true install-kernel="vmlinuz" install-ramdisk="initrd.gz" install-mirror="http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" install-arch=i386 install-method=network
   ```

   - select a language
   - select a location
   - configure your network card. If it fails you will need to configure it manually (choose `back`, drop to a `shell` and issue a `modprobe xen-netfront && exit`. Configure the network card again.
   - select detect network hardware and insert a hostname

   and it starts installing.
6. Fix the install.

   The `xen-blkfront` module isn’t loaded at first so `xen` will fail to boot.

   ```
   (initframfs) modprobe xen-blkfront
   (initramfs) exit
   ```

   Once the host finishes booting, log in and sudo to root. Then enter the following:

   ```
   echo "xen-blkfront" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
   update-initramfs -u
   update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
   ```

<sub>Untested and from memory + googling to fix my memory</sub>