# How do I install Ubuntu in Xen virtual machine?

Tags: xen

Installing Xen on a host machine is easy, but installing an operating system inside a Xen virtual machine is poorly documented. Assume that the system I wish to setup:

- uses paravirtualization.
- uses an image file instead of LVM.
- has the kernel and initial RAM disk residing on the host machine instead of in the virtual machine image.

Where do I get the appropriate kernel and initial RAM disk files? How do I install the operating system in the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way, would be using a graphical interface such as virt-manager. If you want to do it from command line, here is another post were they explain it:
[How do I use Xen hypervisor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56432/how-do-i-use-xen-hypervisor/61774#61774)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Xen Tools from [here](http://xen-tools.org/software/xen-tools/) and then use the command line tool to setup your PV Ubuntu VM per your specifications.

I've personally used these tools via the `debootstrap` method for a PV Debian VM and had terrific results.

More information on Xen Tools can be found [here](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_tools).

**Keep in mind** (taken from Xen Tools link): `The biggest limitation is that it can only install a limited set of guests. The version of xen-tools in Debian testing can install most versions of Debian or Ubuntu, and also has support for CentOS 5 and 6. (The CentOS support is done using rinse rather than debootstrap.)`

Hope this helps.